# What is the meaning of INDEX_COMMENT from the STATISTICS table?

Tags: mariadb

**MariaDB** provides the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-statistics-table) table. After `COMMENT` there is a column `INDEX_COMMENT`, but the meaning is currently undocumented on their site.

Does anybody know the purpose of `INDEX_COMMENT`?

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: The documentation is current, so that would be MariaDB 10.3. But I get the same output in MariaDB 10.0.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-index/

```
index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'            -- It probably comes from here
```

That existed at least as far back as MySQL 5.5.

Comment: I thought that line went into the `COMMENT` column, because the docs mention that it contains the *"Index comments from the CREATE INDEX statement."*. We'd have to test it some time.

Comment: @Code4R7 - One of the options of _table_option_ is `COMMENT [=] 'string'`.  Yes, a test should confirm (or refute) what I am saying.